# Mathematica problem- consecutive integers

Tags: education

Question:

The sequence of consecutive integers 140, 141, 142, 143, 144, 145, 146, 147, 148 consists only of composite (non-prime) numbers, and has length 9.  Find the longest sequence of consecutive composite numbers in the range [1, 7919], and give the length of this sequence. Note that 7919 is a prime.

I received help previously and he suggested to try this

```
{Prime @@ Ordering[#, -1] + 1, Max@# - 1} &@
Differences@Prime@Range@PrimePi@7919
```

The problem is I'm a beginner in Mathematica, and I am having trouble understanding his input as he's more advanced. Is there another way to write this to get the longest sequence of consecutive composite integers?

Comment: It was from reddit, but I didn't get a response back. I thought asking stackexchange for help

Comment: Possibly easier to understand is `Max[Map[Length, Split[CompositeQ[Range[7919]]]]]`. One can run it from the inside out to see what role each part plays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find the length of the longest sequence of non primes

```
tmp = PrimeQ@Range[7919];
Max[Length /@ DeleteCases[Split[tmp], {True ..}]]

(* 33 *)
```

Alternatively

```
Max[Count[#, False] & /@ Split[tmp]]
```

find the sequence:

```
SequencePosition[tmp, ConstantArray[False, 33]]
(* {{1328, 1360}} *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Let's try to do this at a beginner's level and leave you with at least some work to do on your own.

Knowing which numbers are prime and which are composite is a good start. To do that you want to do the same thing to every number out to 7919. "Do the same thing to every number in a list" should get you to think `Map`. What do you want to do? Test for primality. So

```
p = Map[PrimeQ, Range[7919]]
```

will give you a list of `True` and `False` telling you whether each number was prime or composite and that is what you want to test. You should manually check some of those and make certain you understand how `PrimeQ` and `Map` and `Range` worked.

Now let's see if we can verify there are 9 consecutive composites. `MatchQ` will test a list for a pattern and tell you `True` or `False` which means the pattern either matched or it didn't match. But you have some primes and composites before those 9 and have some primes and composites after. So you need to tell `MatchQ` to look for "stuff" followed by your 9 followed by "more stuff." Mathematica has pattern matching things to match "stuff." So if you try

```
MatchQ[p, {__, False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False, __}]
```

Notice that I used two `_` at the beginning and at the end of that.Then it will return `True` telling you that yes it was able to find that pattern. You should look up `__` in the help system and understand how that works and is different from just one `_` or two or even three `_` in a row.

If you make a longer and longer list of those `False` it will continue returning `True` again and again, until you get out to some length where it will return `False` letting you know there are not that many composites in a row. I leave it to you to figure out how many `False` in a row it can find.

But then the second question in your homework problem asks you to find where this pattern appears. To do that you need to know how many numbers appear before your string of `False`. So let's extract "stuff." You can do that with `Replace` by "naming" the "stuff." Notice how I name "stuff" to be x in the next line and how that differs from the previous line. By naming it x I can then do things with x, like use x again inside `Replace`. `Replace` is going to match, just like `MatchQ` did.

```
Replace[p, {x__, False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False,False, __}->{x}]
```

That returns 113 `True` and `False`. (How are you going to tell that there are 113? Perhaps by counting them. Or you might better use a function in Mathematica to tell you how long a list is.) That says there are 113 numbers that appear before the 9 consecutive composite numbers. If you check the numbers from 114 to 114+8 you will see they are all composite. (And how would you do that? Either by hand, or perhaps by using `Map` and `PrimeQ` and `Range`.)

Now you just need to do something similar with your longer list of `False` until you find where your longer list of composite appear.

Read the help pages for every one of the functions used here. Study those pages until you can understand why these functions did what they did. Try examples. Figure out how to use these for other things, like the homework you will probably have next week.

Note that there are always at least a dozen different ways of accomplishing anything in Mathematica and at least a couple of those are completely incomprehensible. When someone else shows you a different way of doing this then that is just another one of those dozen (or more) ways. A favorite thing for people to do is to start replacing commands like `Map` with cryptic punctuation characters that are abbreviations in Mathematica for actually spelling out the name of the function and using `[` and `]` after the name. You can learn how to do that later. Get the functions figured out first.

Comment: This tutorial is much appreciated.